# Why is one directory's file larger than 4kB?

Tags: directory, ls, ext4

I have a directory on my EXT4 filesystem that's showing up as larger than the usual 4kB:

```
$ ls -l
total 24
drwxrwxr-x 2 jvilla jvilla  4096 May 24 17:57 'Season 1'
drwxrwxr-x 2 jvilla jvilla 12288 Sep  3 16:04 'Season 2'
drwxrwxr-x 2 jvilla jvilla  4096 Sep  6 11:23 'Season 3'
drwxrwxr-x 2 jvilla jvilla  4096 Oct  9 11:16 'Season 9'
```

Why might this occur? How can I see what exactly is making it so (relatively) large?